# Zend Framework 2 url helper

Tags: zend-framework2

I am wondering why there is no id parameter shown. The generated URL is: 'http://example.org/editroom' but I expected 'http://example.org/editroom/2'. What did I miss?

Controller-code:

```
echo "<a href='" . $this->url('home', array('action' => 'editroom', 'id' => $room->getId())) . "' title='Bearbeiten des Eintrags'>Bearbeiten</a>;";
```

Comment: @sroes thanks for your advice. I mixed the name of the route, the route name was editroom instead of home - :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably didn't define the id parameter in the home route. You need to add a child route to allow additional parameters:

```
'home' => array(
    'type'    => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route'    => '/[:controller[/[:action]]]',
        'constraints' => array(
            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
            'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
        ),
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
            'action'     => 'index',
        ),
    ),
    'may_terminate' => true,
    'child_routes' => array(
        'wildcard' => array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Wildcard',
            'options' => array(
                'key_value_delimiter' => '/',
                'param_delimiter' => '/',
            ),
        ),
    ),
)
```

Then you call it like this:

```
echo "<a href='" . $this->url('home/wildcard', array('action' => 'editroom', 'id' => $room->getId())) . "' title='Bearbeiten des Eintrags'>Bearbeiten</a>;";
```

Comment: As I already mentioned I mixed up the name of the route. Thanks for your help @sroes!